# NiFI custom processor ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I am trying to load a custom NiFi processor, but cannot get NiFi to load all my .nar dependencies, despite trying various pom.xml configurations. I've come across some similar questions on SO but have not found the answer to this issue.

I package my processor as a .nar with mvn clean install, then copy the .nar to NIFI_HOME/lib. Currently I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager`. Current pom dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <nifi.version>1.1.2</nifi.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
        <version>${nifi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-utils</artifactId>
        <version>${nifi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-standard-services-api-nar</artifactId>
        <version>${nifi.version}</version>
        <type>nar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-ssl-context-service</artifactId>
        <version>${nifi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-ssl-context-service-api</artifactId>
        <version>${nifi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-processor-utils</artifactId>
        <version>${nifi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My nar's NIFI_HOME/.../bundled-dependencies/ contains all specified jars:

```
bcpkix-jdk15on-1.55.jar                joda-time-2.9.7.jar
bcprov-jdk15on-1.55.jar                nifi-api-1.1.2.jar
commons-codec-1.9.jar                  nifi-processor-utils-1.1.2.jar
commons-io-2.5.jar                     nifi-security-utils-1.1.2.jar
commons-lang3-3.4.jar                  nifi-ssl-context-service-1.1.2.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar                nifi-ssl-context-service-api-1.1.2.jar
httpclient-4.4.1.jar                   nifi-utils-1.1.2.jar
httpcore-4.4.1.jar
```

Full stack trace:

```
2017-03-13 11:11:23,146 ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to launch NiFi due to java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.nifi.processor.Processor: Provider com.alar.nifi.processors.GetIBright could not be instantiated
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.nifi.processor.Processor: Provider com.alar.nifi.processors.GetIBright could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.nifi.nar.ExtensionManager.loadExtensions(ExtensionManager.java:116) ~[nifi-nar-utils-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]
    at org.apache.nifi.nar.ExtensionManager.discoverExtensions(ExtensionManager.java:97) ~[nifi-nar-utils-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:139) ~[nifi-runtime-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:262) ~[nifi-runtime-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/HttpClientConnectionManager
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace for the class not found exception?

Comment: Hi, yes I have added the stack trace to the question

Comment: @JustinMoore hope you have restarted NiFi server after placing the `.jar` files under `lib` folder

Comment: @Pons yep, I have restarted NiFi, the error occurs when it tries to load the new custom processor on startup. Also - it is a .nar file, not .jar

Comment: Nothing is jumping out at me so far. If you are able to share your Maven projects I would be happy to take a look.

Comment: One thing that is not correct (but should not be related to this problem) is you shouldn't be including the controller service JARs inside your NAR. Your NAR pom should have a NAR dependency on the controller service API, and your processors pom should have a provided dependency on the API so that it is available at compile time but not included at build time. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Maven+Projects+for+Extensions#MavenProjectsforExtensions-LinkingProcessorsandControllerServices

Comment: @BryanBende thanks for the advice! I removed the unneeded build dependencies and was able to get this working, see answer below

Answer (score 3):

Resolved this by modifying my single pom.xml into separate build (nar) and compile (jar) pom.xml files, with a parent pom.xml. Not sure why it did not work before but I have included the pom.xml files below

**parent pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>nifi-ibright-bundle</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <groupId>com.alar.nifi</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <nifi.version>1.1.2</nifi.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>nifi-ibright-processor</module>
        <module>nifi-ibright-nar</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.alar.nifi</groupId>
                <artifactId>nifi-ibright-processor</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement> 
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
                <artifactId>nifi-nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-incubating</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**nifi-ibright-nar/pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.alar.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-ibright-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.alar.nifi</groupId>
    <artifactId>nifi-ibright-processor</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
            <version>${nifi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${nifi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-ssl-context-service-api</artifactId>
            <version>${nifi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-processor-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${nifi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```